# When is it better to use Resources.Load in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello everyone I recently learned how to use `Resources.Load`, but I have a question, when should I use it?

For example, I have a button that has 2 different sprites. What is the best way to do, load these two sprites in advance in the editor and turn one on and off the other? Or at the `Start`, load it `Resources.Load<Sprite>` and replace the sprite in the Source Image?
Please explain when and how best to use `Resources.Load`. Examples will be useful

Comment: Resources.Load loads an asset into memory, it will not get cleared until you call the Resources.UnloadAsset. Thus loading a resource multiple times will not have a big hit on performance if it is already loaded. However, if you know every resource that you will load ahead of time, it can save a tiny amount of processing, or larger amounts for bigger assets, to load resources beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

`Resources.Load` is useful for loading prefabs common to many scenes. And for editor scripts.

Nevertheless, the devs will be deprecating `Resources.Load` at one point, but backed off from it, because there are good reasons to keep it around until/if they replace it with something better.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some Resource not use it at all time. you can use `Resources.Load`
when you use before. it's about your memory.